# update query with where clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

very simple question - I want to update one record only that matches 2 parameters.

Should I be doing it like this:

```
Model.where(:email =>"test@test.com",:code => "chejd").update(:password => "password").first
```

I have found examples using update_all but I only want to update a maximum of 1 record.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Check if this works with your DBMS and DB adapter:

```
Model.where(conditions).limit(1).update_all(changes) # => 1
```

**Update:**

The `limit()` and `update_all()` combo is an [example in the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-update_all), so it's probably supported by most DB adapters.

Comment: If you don't use pure SQL in your methods, Rails will translate the query into the proper syntax SQL, depending on the DB adapter.

Comment: This is what I need - haven't done much testing but seems fine. thanks

Comment: The example correctly establishes a specific record sequence using the `order()` specifier before the `limit()`. This is important to avoid updating some arbitrary record within the set that matches the `where()` specification.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to above answer. If you want to update either the first or last record, you can append that and can run the query.

`Model.where(conditions).first.update(changes)` or `Model.where(conditions).last.update(changes)`

first - fetches the first record ordered by primary key
last - fetches the last record ordered by primary key